# How to remove specific shower spout; no set screw?

Tags: bathroom, diverter, spout

I need to replace the existing shower spout (with diverter). It has a hole on the bottom side (close to the wall) but there is no set screw there for unscrewing. I have cut out the caulking. I have tried pulling it out and unscrewing the whole thing, but I'm worried about trying too hard and snapping a pipe. I can only rotate it slightly clock-wise, but that's the wrong way to unscrew it.

Can anyone identify the model of the spout? That would be useful in finding out how it should get removed.

[image: The spout from the bottom side]
[image: The spout from the bottom side, slightly different angle to capture the screw threads]
[image: The spout from the typical side]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These spouts are all fairly standard no matter the brand. It should unscrew counter-clockwise. Most that I've seen don't have set screws. If yours has one but it is missing there shouldn't be a problem unscrewing the faucet from the wall stub although it could be a little stubborn.
They often get corroded so you may want to spray some WD40 or another decalcifier up there using the straw they provide since the actual screw connection is usually toward the front of the faucet.  Patience and a little elbow grease should do it.

Comment: Thank you HoneyDo. It did unscrew counter-clockwise. I decided to risk it a bit more, and it gave way, just by sticking a screwdriver up the opening and rotating.